# Outlook 365 - Change temp folder location for attachments

Tags: office365, microsoft-outlook-365

I've been facing a problem when trying to open attached files on Outlook 365 on Windows 7. It doesn't happen on Windows 10. I guess Windows 7 has some trouble handling the long path + the long filename.

When the attached file has a filename too long, it shows up an error at trying to open it.

The path to the temp folder is similar to this:

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.Outlook\HZX66EOP
```

On older versions of Office, I would change the temp location directy in Registry to:

```
 C:\Otk_temp\
```

Reg Path

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security [OutlookSecureTempFolder]

The problem is: Outlook 365 won't allow me to set this by changing the path on Registry. Every time I change the value in Registry, it will be overwritten back to the default value once I launch Outlook 365 again.

Is there a way to change this temp folder location on Outlook 365?

Comment: Is this a business O365 setup? If so, policies may be set by your administrators. The temp folder location is a substantial part of the default security capabilities of Outlook as the OS can block executables and other likely dangerous file types from running there, or require enhanced security when they do run.